# Build docker image with a custom name using Spring Boot Maven plugin

Tags: spring, docker, maven, pom.xml

In my pom.xml file, I configured the imageName to be the project name by default:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${project.name}</imageName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run `mvn spring-boot:build-image`, it works fine.

When I try to override the image name using `mvn spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=customname`, I was expecting to get a docker image named `customname`. I'm still getting the project name instead. This means that maven plugin is still using `${project.name}`.

Am using the command in a wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case the name of image always comes from plugin configuration `<imageName>${project.name}</imageName>`. If you want to support both options to specify target image name (i.e. maven base configuration and CLI) you may take advantage of using maven properties, i.e.:

```xml
<properties>
  <module.image.name>${project.name}</module.image.name>
</properties>


<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${module.image.name}</imageName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

after that both `mvn spring-boot:build-image` and `mvn spring-boot:build-image -Dmodule.image.name=customname` (note another name of system property) will work as expected